# Is it a good idea to do "functional-style" if-as-expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, expression

I have a question. I usually code in a language like Kotlin, Rust, and Elm. These languages have a feature which enables me to produce a value from an if or switch expression, something like this:

Example in rust:

```rust
let x = 10
let biggerThanFive =
  if x > 5 {
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
```

Example in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val x = 10
val biggerThanFive =
  if (x > 5) {
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
```

Now in Javascript, I rarely stumble upon a code which uses if as expression (I usually use this with the help of anonymous function and arrow function)

```js
const x = 10
const biggerThanFive = (() => {
  if(x > 5) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
})()
```

Instead, it's usually done like this

```js
const x = 10
let biggerThanFive

if(x > 5) {
  biggerThanFive = true
}
else {
  biggerThanFive = false
}
```

Is there any reason **not** to do the if-as-expression technique in Javascript?

Comment: The reason is that `if` is a statement in JavaScript, not an expression. Hence you cannot use it as an expression. It kind of sucks, honestly, but it is what it is.

Comment: I think people would normally reach for a ternary here if they want an expression. `biggerThanFive = v > 5 ? 'something' : 'something else'`

Comment: Just a hint: your code (with arrow function) is incorrect. biggerThanFive would be a function not a value. You have to execute this function by appending `()` to it to get the same result as in rust, elm or procedural javascript;

Comment: @CoronA yes, thank you for spotting the mistake, I'll edit it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use the expression directly?

```
const
    x = 10,
    biggerThanFive = x > 5;
```

Comment: Yes, this is quite plausible for the example I have provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return just true or false, you can put the expression directly into the assignment.

```
const x = 10;
const biggerThanFive = x > 5;
```

---

But, if you want to return other results based on the condition, you can try the conditional ternary operator.

```
const x = 10;
const biggerThanFive = x > 5 ? "Return when it's true" : "Return when it's false";
```

---

For more information you can consult the documentation: [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

That code you wrote isn't so functional, what with the impure x hanging out there:

```
const x = 10
const biggerThanFive = (() => {
  if(x > 5) {
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
})()
```

Also that immediately executed anonymous function is unidiomatic and super confusing to read.

If I wanted to do a quick comparison in a functional style and in javascript, I'd do:

```
const biggerThanFive = _in => _in > 5
const isBigger = biggerThanFive(10)
```

If I found myself doing this a lot, I might introduce a utility function that would let me do it this way:

```
const isTrue = (fn, _in) => fn(_in)
const res = isTrue(_in => _in>5, 19)
```

which let's me avoid having to give the anonymous function a name or explicitly invoke it.